# Specify the Number of Times that Test Explorer will Run a Test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, test-explorer

**Background**

I have a project that I am currently unit testing. This project includes code that talks to a piece of hardware asynchronously. The objective for the software library is to control the hardware and provide workarounds for any bugs that the device has. I have unit tests in place that test out the functionality of the software (where the functionality includes controlling aforementioned hardware device). As I tweak my software, I fail the unit tests less and less (eventually I will not fail them because I will have written all necessary workarounds for the hardware). So, I need to run these tests as many times as possible and gather the results.

**Question**

In Visual Studio 2015 (within test-explorer), is there a way to specify the number of times that a unit-test should run?

Comment: "I need to run these tests as many times as possible and gather the results." What would be the trigger? When you make a change to the code? or just run in background?

Comment: @Spock Neither. The failure is dependent on the behavior of the hardware. I can use the unit tests as a means to exploit that behavior and bring out the failures, so I can write the appropriate software workaround.

Comment: I don't understand, why would running a test more than once (i'm assuming in a single run of your suite?) matter?  Unit Tests should run independently of each other, and the order shouldn't matter, so what would be accomplished by running a single unit test more than one for a single build?  If you need to run your tests do to code changes, just run the tests.  I guess I'm not understanding your use case around your question.

Comment: @Kritner Think about the hardware. It can function independent of the software (and sometime randomly). My software (which controls the hardware) depends on the behavior of said hardware device. Now do you see the use case?

Comment: @Kritner It's kind of confusing, let's just say that the hardware has some quirks that causes it to behave randomly at times. So the more test results I can get the better.

Comment: Agree with @Kritner. If OP about Unit Tests, then this is case is not a Unit Tests. The tests are not independent from each other also it is not independent from hardware. Hence not a Unit Test. It is an Integration Test. Check the definition.

Comment: @Spock has nothing to do with the question. But thanks.